# How to select a cell in a tableView thats inside an alertView in UIAutomation?

Tags: automated-testing, ios

I am a beginner to UIAutomation. I wanted to know how do I tap one of the cells in a tableView thats inside an alert.
As per Apple's UI automation documentation an alert will by default tap the cancel button if you dont specifically handle the alert and return true.

I tried the below written code (found at Apple developer). But this is still tapping the cancel button.

```
// second alert box "Nearby listings:"
UIATarget.onAlert = function onAlert(alert) {
    var title = alert.name();
    UIALogger.logWarning("Alert with title ’" + title + "’     encountered!");
    if (title == "Nearby listings:") {
        target.frontMostApp().alert().tableViews()["Empty list"].cells()[2].tap(); //    tapping the second cell
        return true; // bypass default handler
    }
}
```

I would highly appreciate any kind of help.

Comment: Are you trying to do this with an IOS app or something else?

Comment: @DanSnell iOS App

Answer (score 2):

You may want to take a look at the index position of the cell you are trying to tap.

I am guessing that:

```
target.frontMostApp().alert().tableViews()["Empty list"].cells()[2].tap();
```

The `[2]` is likely the index position of that element in your collection. Take a look at the position of the cell in your collection and set the index accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I moved my onAlert to the top (before the instance of UITarget)and that made it work. It was not even calling the onAlert function before.

Comment: Great - you can add it as an answer below with the code you changed and accepted as an answer.  Good luck!